# Classical Mechanics, Euler-Lagrange equation, Conservative Force.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I’m studying classical mechanics with Mathematical Methods of classical mechanics, by Arnold, doing some exercises lists and got stuck on this part.

Being . Consider a material point of
mass 1 moving under the constant conservative force  and linked to$$V=\{(x,y,z)\vert z=W(x,y)\}$$ This means that, the point is linked to the graph of the W function. Write the Lagrangian.

Comment: Just so you know, there has been several Portuguese (and Spanish) editions of this book. Not too easy to find them, it seems, but maybe you could.

Comment: Please revise the Lagrangian posted as $\bar L(q_1,q_2,\dot q_1\dot q_2)=\frac{1}{2}((\dot q_1)^2 + (\dot q_1)^2) - W(q_1,q_2)$ I think there are some typos...

Comment: Thank you, you were right!

Comment: The motivation is that the equation $\ddot x+c(x)\dot x+g(x)=0$ is often interpreted as the movement of a particle in the "landscape" defined by the "height function" $G(x)=\int g(x)dx$ and under friction/dissipation with coefficient $c$. The task can be used to establish how correct this picture is.

Answer (score 2):

As $F$ s conservative, then $F = -\nabla U\Rightarrow U = z + C_0$

taking $C_0=0$ and assuming unity mass, the movement kinetic energy is

$$
T = \frac 12(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2) = \frac 12\left(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+(W_x(x,y)\dot x+W_y(x,y)\dot y)^2\right)
$$

and the lagrangian

$$
L = T-U =\frac 12\left((1+W_x^2(x,y))\dot x^2+2W_x(x,y)W_y(x,y)\dot x\dot y+(1+W_y^2(x,y))\dot y^2\right)-W(x,y)
$$